# Automated testing tools to simulate 1000+ concurrent users 

Tags: php, scalability

What programs or methods can I use to test a PHP script with 1000 connections at the same time? I'd typically like to measure the following, by sending HTTP requests :

- file response time
- how many times it failed

I've done some search on Google but found nothing useful.

Can you recommend a scalability testing tool like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ApacheBench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

> ab is a tool for benchmarking your Apache Hypertext Transfer Protocol
>   (HTTP) server. It is designed to give you an impression of how your
>   current Apache installation performs. This especially shows you how
>   many requests per second your Apache installation is capable of
>   serving.

If you are looking  for a Hosted / Paid Solution , I recommend [Blitz](http://blitz.io/).

Comment: also see [seige](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write a PHP (or any other server language) to asynchronously call your script as many times as you would like.

That said, you really should include a lot more information with your questions so people are better equipped to assist you.

```
<?php
    $numUsers = 1000;
    for( $i = 0; $i < $numUsers; $i++ ) {
        exec( /* call your script here */ );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your idea is interesting. But I also wanted to simulate the real users and see the result of each HTTP request.

Comment: Note that scaling into the thousands of simultaneous connections per second [is hardly something one would call _simple_](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

Comment: @Ben Roux: I was doing something similar.but will you script generate concurrent connections?

Answer (score 0):

I think that ultimately you're looking for stress testing. If you're feeling adventurous then you could write a program or script (with threading enabled) and run x threads at once, but that's probably not a good idea.

I'd recommend having a look at [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/15-free-functionality-and-load-testing-tools-for-web-applications/) site. It has a batch of free stress / functionality testing utilities that should get you the results you want.